# How to print xmlhttp response?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am getting some information  from database, this information is getting back into JSON format now I need to print this JSON information. But my code is not working **getCountryDetails.php** is php file for interacting with the database. Following code is the script, When I click the button It intersects with database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#quickSearch").click(function(){       
            var countries = [];
            $.each($("#select-choice-1 option:selected"), function(){ 
                countries.push($(this).val());
            });

    if (countries == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else {    
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    //myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);


                    myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            xmlhttp.open("GET","webservices/getCountryDetails.php?q="+countries,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        } 
        });
    });
    function myFunction(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(response);
        var i;
        var out = "<table>";

        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            out += "<tr><td>" +
            arr[i].Name +
            "</td><td>" +
            arr[i].City +
            "</td><td>" +
            arr[i].Country +
            "</td></tr>";
        }
        out += "</table>"
        document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Define "not working". Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the JavaScript console. Does it report any errors? Look at the Net tab. Is the request being made? Does it get a response? Do they contain the data you expect?

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, what's with not using `$.ajax()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `countries` will never be an empty string, you've defined it as an array

```
var countries = [];

...

if (countries == "") { // always fail
```

secondly, you can't concantenate an array into a string, and XMLHttpRequest doesn't accept arrays

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","webservices/getCountryDetails.php?q=" + countries, true);
```

Thirdly, you seem to be using jQuery, so why not use it as it does accept an array

```
$.ajax({
    url  : 'webservices/getCountryDetails.php',
    data : countries
}).done(myFunction);
```

Comment: thanks for your replay, but there is no need of ajax, because after getting the data it is forwarded to next page, Above I am just checking how to get data. Please tell me how to get data and forward this data to next page, I am waiting for your replay

Comment: But `XMLHttpRequest` **is** ajax ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am telling what I am doing, I have to create one app(hotel-reservation)for mobile, and through this app we will search hotels for a given city (on page1), we have to fetch data in JSON format, show this data on different page(on page2)